# Excel vba import data from another workbook and compare

Tags: excel, vba

I have one excel workbook "source" (with data parameters) like :

**NAME**    **PARAMS1**    **PARAMS2**   ...
name1   param1_1   param1_2  ...
name2   param2_1   param2_2  ...
name3   param3_1   param3_2  ...

In another workbook "report" I have column for example "B" where I have my "names" as well like:
.A.....B.....C
....name1...
....name1...
....name2...
....name3...
....name2...
...
Now I want to:
1. Import data from "source" to "report"
2. Check in column if I have the same name
3. If I find the same name I put value(param) of corresponding name in column for example"C"

I have one big Please. I need working example not advice like I should learn about Vlookup or collections or arrays.
regards
Jack

Comment: Have you tried using a `VLOOKUP` on `name`?

Comment: No. I didn't. But I have code using application.match refer to please:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242554/vba-make-code-simplier

Answer (score 1):

OK I managed to do it on my own.

```
Sub FBA_test_1()

Dim products As Variant
Dim productsWithParams As Variant
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'products = Array("one", "two", "three")
products =Workbooks("sourceFile.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A4").Value

'productsWithParams = Array(Array("one", 10, 11), Array("two", 20, 21), Array("three", 30, 31))
productsWithParams = Workbooks("sourceFile.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:C4").Value

For x = LastRow To 1 Step -1

    ' if value not found inside the array using the "MATCH" function
    pos = Application.Match(Range("$A$" & x).Value, products, 0)
    If IsError(pos) Then
        Range("$B$" & x).Value = "ERROR - "
    Else ' successful "MATCH" inside the array
        Range("$B$" & x).Value = pos
        Range("$C$" & x).Value = products(pos, 1) 'name
        Range("$D$" & x).Value = productsWithParams(pos, 2) 'param1
        Range("$E$" & x).Value = productsWithParams(pos, 3) 'param2

   End If
Next
End Sub
```

I use two arrays one normal and one 2d because 2d doesn't work with Application.Match
Regards